# Enabling users to create custom forms in RCP

Tags: user-interface, eclipse-rcp, gui-builder

I have an Eclipse RCP project, and I need to enable users to create custom views for our information. I see basically two options.

1. Embed VEP or [some other visual GUI builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942696/what-eclipse-gui-builder-plugin-do-you-suggest). It would need to be: easy enough to use; have some hooks to compile generated files and make them available to my application; localizable; and the license must permit such use. Which GUI builders satisfy these requirements?
2. Generate GUI on the fly from text files in a human-writable format (e.g. XML, but not necessarily). There are some libraries which do this: [CookSWT](http://cookxml.yuanheng.org/cookswt/index.html), [XSWT](http://www.coconut-palm-software.com/the_new_visual_editor/doku.php?id=xswt:home), [JellySWT](http://commons.apache.org/jelly/jellyswt.html), [SWTML](http://sheelapps.com/index.php?p=SWTML.HomePage&action=view). However, none of them seem to be actively developed at the moment, and some of them don't even allow event handlers (though this can be worked around). Are there any projects I've missed? Which of them will work with the current SWT versions?

Option 2 seems both easier to get working and have less potential for bugs.

Finally, is there some better way than these 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at [redView](http://redview.org)? It comes with a GUI-designer.

Comment: Didn't know about it. I'll check it out.